# I have a set of vector $\{(2,1,2), (3,4,8)\}$ how will i know that whether it is linearly dependent or independent basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the rank=2 which is equal to unknown number that means it is linearly independent but in the given answer it said that it is linearly dependent. 
Any tip please

Comment: Did you try reducing it to row echelon form ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Two vectors can't be a basis for a $3$-dimensional space such as $\mathbb R^3$

Answer (score 2):

They are linearly independent but not span $\mathbb{R}^3$, and therefore cannot be a basis. At least three vectors are needed to span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether $\{(2, 1, 2), (3, 4, 8)\}$ are L.I. (linearly independent), try row reducing:
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    1 & 4 & 0 \\
    2 & 8 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
Why? Because two vectors are L.I. if the only solution to the following equation is the trivial solution, i.e., $a_1\vec{x_1} + a_2\vec{x_2} = 0$ where $a_1, a_2$ are scalars. So, write:

$a_1 \begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    1 \\
    2 \\
  \end{bmatrix} + a_2 \begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    4 \\
    8 \\
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

which is the same as saying:
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 0 \\
    1 & 4 & 0 \\
    2 & 8 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
If you row reduce this matrix, you'll get:
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}

See how the above matrix implies that $a_1 =a_2 =0$? This tells you that $\{(2, 1, 2), (3, 4, 8)\}$ are L.I.

Now, note that you do not have a pivot in every *row*(the bottom-most row is composed of all zeros). This means that you do not have enough vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, $\{(2, 1, 2), (3, 4, 8)\}$ does not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.